# Assembly across many SSIS packages in script task

Tags: c#, reflection, ssis

Is there a way to share the same custom dll class library in a Script Component (*Data Flow level*) in SSIS without passing through the GAC? 
If this is possible through reflection, how to debug the SSIS task?

[After trying this solution](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2014/06/25/how-to-load-an-assembly-in-a-ssis-script-task-that-isnt-in-the-gac/), the message appears: Warning: Cannot attach the  VSTA debugger. Re-starting the debugging may resolve the problem. Note in my case it is in the data flow, it is in the  *public override void PreExecute()* method.